# Auto pause in embeded video

Tags: html, youtube, vimeo

I am wanting to have a video that automatically pauses at a set time and then the user have to press the play button. I have already managed to do a play and stop on embeded YouTube but I am unable to play it once it stops. Ideally want to be able to do this in Vimeo. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can you a "sleep" timer and then use the pause command, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<button onclick="playVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
<button onclick="pauseVid()" type="button">Pause Video</button><br> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script> 
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

async function playVid() { 
  vid.play();
  // Sleep timer with 2000s
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  // After this, pause
  vid.pause();
} 

function pauseVid() { 
  vid.pause(); 
} 
</script> 

<p>Video courtesy of <a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp

Comment: Hi thanks, is there any chance you can give me an example of how to do this with the below embed code having say 2 random pauses in the video.

Comment: <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/396683740?h=298223c715&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Doncaster Hub and Spoke"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>